# From 2 df one with Country code and Country name and other df with phone number of different len(11 to 15) try to find the county code for each ph no

Tags: python, dataframe

> I have 2 data frame:

1. 1st data frame : Country Code(Country Name & Country Code):

| Country Name | Country Code | Country Code Length |
| --- | --- | --- |
| India | 91 | 2 |
| Nepal | 977 | 3 |
| American Samoa | 1 | 1 |

2. 2nd Dataframe User details(Username, Phone Numbers with country code):

| User name | Phone Numbers with country code | Phone number length |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Jay | 919988665500 | 12 |
| XYZ | 9771234665500 | 13 |
| abc | 12233445500 | 11 |
| cvv | 9779988665500 | 13 |

Need a final Table like the below one:

| User name | Clean Phone Number | County code | County Name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Jay | 91-9988665500 | 91 | India |
| XYZ | 977-1234665500 | 977 | Nepal |
| abc | 1-2233445500 | 1 | American Samoa |
| cvv | 977-9988665500 | 977 | Nepal |

my python script. which is not helping me with the right output.

```js
for number in df['Phone']:
    for code in country_df['Country Code']:
        if code in number[:4]:
                df["new_no"] = f"{code}-{number[len(code_to_check):]}"
                df['Country'] = country_df['Country']  
        elif code not in number[:4]:
            df["new_no"] = df['Phone']
            df['Country'] = country_df['Country']
```

Comment: Please don't post your code as a picture. We can't run a picture. Edit your question and include the code in it.

Comment: Done. I have added the code script.